# How to transform a number into array. Java

Tags: java

I want to transform a number into array.
For example...

```
num = 7
```

to

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: By writing some code :-)

Comment: @JavaCrawler At least put your code in a code-tag

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
int []list = new int[num];
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Another possible solution is to use the Java 8 streams:
`int[] arr = IntStream.range(0, 7).map(x -> x + 1).toArray();`

A neat and tidy oneliner ;)

Comment: You are the first one to get this simple task right without mistakes. Well done!

Comment: @wassgren awesome i never thought of it.

Comment: @wassgren Shorter: `int[] arr = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num).toArray();`

Comment: thanks @CoolGuy, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Integer[] ints = new Integer[x];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
   ints[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're want to create an array from 1 to the number.

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  list[i] = i+1;
}
```

Comment: Nope.`ArrayOutOfBounds Exception`!

Comment: You're right, I guess I wasn't thinking clearly. Should be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

In java you have to declare the variables first.
This means that variables are strongly typed.

You cannot convert a variable into an array.

However you can create a new variable that is an array.

```
int num = 7;

int[] arr = {num};  // arr is an array containing num
```

Comment: That doesn't make the array { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 } !!

Comment: No but I think the OP has bigger conceptual problems if he wants to convert an integer to an array. Moreover his list was just an example, right?